# Finding the question I've started answering

Tags: discussion, search, draft

So, here's the sequence of events:

1. Read an interesting question, that I think I have an answer for.
2. Start typing up an answer.
3. Realize that my thought isn't completely formed and stop typing the answer.
4. The answer draft is saved.
5. Change computers.
6. Complete the thought to answer the question.
7. Can't find the question again.

Now, theoretically, I should remember enough about the question to be able to search for it, but is there a quicker/easier way to find the question to which I have a saved answer draft?

As a side note, I understand the need to have a limited number of active answer drafts, but why only one?  For example, I start working on a complicated answer, walk away for a couple of minutes, answer a different question, then come back to complete the complicated answer.

Comment: Skip step 5.  There's little point.  Netbook, laptop, whatever.

Comment: For how great SO works, there seems like there ought to be a more elegant way to get back to the answer you were last editing. Adding it as a Favorite seems kludgy and if you forget to do it, or if your machine crashes or what not, then you have this answer draft with no way to get back to it.

Answer (score 2):

In one word: Favorites. Simply add the question to your favorite list and you'll easily find it. I do that many many times. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the switching computers scenario you could always favorite it (toggling the star) and look it up later (sort by ***added***). Bear in mind this is a general purpose method that doesn't take into account the existence of a draft (i.e., there's no indication that a draft is tied to your favorites).

For the other issue I keep the post open in a separate tab till I'm ready to get back to it - that's my draft. If it's a really involved response, such as the ones I've written for bounty questions, I have occasionally copy/pasted to Notepad and saved it off for later.

Comment: awww, not notepad++? :)