# Let me search for my drafts

Tags: feature-request, support, draft

If I start typing an answer, until I post it a draft is automatically saved.

How can I find these drafts?
If there isn't a way, can one please be created?

---

The use case I have is I might start creating a post on my phone, but realize that it requires a lot more typing/effort than the phone easily supports so I want to switch to a another bigger device laptop/desktop.

It can be quite hard to find a specific question using search, so when this happens I read the question ID, which is not that easy on a mobile phone (especially if the title is long) and manually type it in on my laptop.

It would be very handy to click on a "Drafts" button (if one existed) and quickly pick up where I left off.

Comment: IIRC there is only one draft stored server, ever. Anyway: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70818/finding-the-question-ive-started-answering

Comment: @rene OK so there's max 1 draft, but how can you go directly to it? btw I think you found a dup.

Comment: You can't go to it and yours is the first feature request that asks to add that. So I think it is not a dupe.

Comment: You could single handedly close this by clicking the "This solved my case" blue button on top. :-)

Comment: @shad actually, having closed this as a dupe, I think I want to open it again as a FR. Would you mind? If it subsequently gets closed so be it

Comment: @Bohemian done. :)